# Canonical vs natural isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

It’s a quite simple question hanging on my mind.

I hold that canonical isomorphism means an isomorphism without any choice.

Is the usual canonical isomorphism natural isomorphism from the point of view of category theory. If not so, what’s the relation between them?

Comment: I think n.i. is viewed as the formalization of the term c.i.

Comment: It would be interesting whether one could find an example of a "canonical isomorphism" that does not give rise to a natural isomorphism.

Comment: This is 100% a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a natural transformation tries to formalize this idea. The standard example is as follows.

Take the category of finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $k$. There is a functor taking a vector space to its dual, say $F,$ and a functor $G$ taking a vector space to its double dual.

A finite-dimensional vector space is isomorphic to both its dual and double dual, but people typically say that its canonically isomorphic to its double dual but not to its single dual. This is because there *is* a natural transformation between $G$ and the identity functor, but a (fun!) exercise of linear algebra can show there is no natural transformation between $F$ and the identity.

Comment: What's the downvote for? Is there anything incorrect about this answer?

Comment: This seems pretty misleading.  "Canonical" is used in a variety of ways and is far from synonymous with "natural".  And the dual vector space example is not a great one because $F$ is not even the correct type of object to have a natural transformation between it and the identity, being contravariant (there are ways to make sense of the lack of a "natural" isomorphism here but they are not obvious from the definition of a natural transformation).

Comment: The following example is instructive: as you say, there is a natural isomorphism between the double dual functor and the identity functor.  But there are in fact many different such natural isomorphisms (one for each nonzero scalar in the base field).  Only one of these natural isomorphisms is commonly called the "canonical" isomorphism.